# FullCalendar, possible to set selectable false but allow select slot

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, fullcalendar

I'm making an application with [FullCalendar](http://fullcalendar.io/).

I noticed that with `selectable` set to `true`, the user was able to select multiple weeks or time slots which was not desired. On the other hand when I set `selectable` to `false`, then I can no longer use the select action that I want to be triggered when the user selects a time slot. Is there any way that `selectable` feature will remain to `false`, but still each time slot to be selectable on its own, not as part of group of time slots.

Here is my code, passed as array through PHP:

```
'options'=>array(
'header'=>array(
    'left'=>'prev,next,today',
    'center'=>'title',
    'right'=> 'month,agendaWeek,agendaDay',
),
'minTime' => '09:00:00',
'maxTime' => '20:00:00',
'slotDuration' => '01:00:00',
'slotEventOverlap' => false,
'defaultTimedEventDuration' => '01:00:00',
'allDaySlot' => false,
'allDay' => false,
'lazyFetching'=>true,
'weekends' => false,
'selectable' => true,
'height' => 'auto',
'contentHeight' => '150',
// 'selectHelper' => true,
// 'events'=>array(), // pass array of events directly
'select' => new CJavaScriptExpression("function(start, end, jsEvent, view) {
                    var currdisplay = view.name;
                    var check = Date.parse(start) / 1000;
                    var today = Date.parse(new Date()) / 1000;
                    if (currdisplay != 'month' && check >= today) {
                        var start1 = Date.parse(start) / 1000;
                        var end = Date.parse(start) / 1000 + 3600;
                        window.location.href = \"www.somelink.com/?from=\" + start1 + \"&to=\" + end;
                        }}"),
'dayClick' => new CJavaScriptExpression("function(date, jsEvent, view) {
                    var currdisplay = view.name;
                    if (currdisplay == 'month') {
                        $('.calendar').fullCalendar('gotoDate', date);
                        $('.calendar').fullCalendar('changeView', 'agendaWeek');
                    }}"),
```

I have currently a fix, as you probably can see in the code block:

```
var start1 = Date.parse(start) / 1000;
var end = Date.parse(start) / 1000 + 3600;
```

These two lines make sure that if user select 5 time slots, to set the end time 1 hour (3600 seconds) after the start time, and not 5 hours later, but I'm not satisfied with this solution since I don't find it clean, and I don't like that `selectable` feature is still available.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**Imperfect solution for time slots:**

Does this work well enough for you?

http://jsfiddle.net/3E8nk/739/

```
select: (function() {
    var humanSelection = true;
    return function(start, end, jsEvent, view) {
        if(humanSelection) {
            humanSelection = false;
            $('#calendar').fullCalendar('select', start);
            humanSelection = true;
        }
    };
})(),
```

**Solution for days:**

Try using day click to set the background colour to what you want instead.

[See fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/3E8nk/736/)

```
dayClick: (function() {
    var lastThis;
    return function(date, jsEvent, view) {
        if(lastThis)
            lastThis.css('background-color', 'white');
        lastThis = $(this);
        $(this).css('background-color', 'lightblue');
    }
})(),
```

Comment: hi Richard, what i m after actually is some sort of slotClick instead of day click, i want my code to be trigered on selecting a unique time slot and not a set of time slots

Comment: @nikolas This can't be done properly with the library as it is now but shouldn't be very hard to extend. I provided an imperfect solution above but if you decide to work on the source then I think arshaw would appreciate the pull request :)

Comment: well, it seems that this does the trick as well..pity that there is no native option from fullcalendar, but this seems to work ok :)

Comment: on the event callback ive set also
                $items[] = array(
                    'title'=>'appointment',
                    'start'=> $from,
                    'end'=>$to,
                    'color'=>'#CC0000',
                    'selectable'=>false,
                );
but the slot remains selectable...any idea..??

Comment: @RichardLöwenström I am using Full calendar 4 version. it does not work. Do you have any other solution for version 4. Thanks.